# How can I programmatically detect the attachment of a portable USB device?

Tags: linux, usb, libusb

In Windows OS, when a USB device is attached or detached, WindowProc receives a `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message having parameters `wParam` and `lParam` in which I can find out which device is attached or detached.

How can I programmatically detect the connection of a portable USB device at any time when the program is already running on Linux in the same way? Preferably using `libusb` and without using `udev` and there should be no call to external utilities like `lsusb`.

I've looked thru similar questions in this forum and alas found no answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way. `libusb_hotplug_register_callback` saves me.